# How to install ROS electric on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [ROS_electric_installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu).

I can't install electric on ubuntu 12.04.

How to do that?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42091/how-to-install-ros-electric-on-ubuntu-12.04?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot officially.

Duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/37981/electric-running-under-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-lts/

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0